# How do i get user details to autofill into entry boxes after i get them from my sql database

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry form; when the user types in their username and presses the button, I want it to autofill with their details from the sql database.  I know you need to use state=DISABLED, if im correct, but I dont know how to use this.

```
self.userentered=StringVar()

        #fill out entry form
        Label(self.master,text="Final steps to entering your race...",font=(20),fg="blue").place(x=10,y=10)

        Label(self.master,text="Username:",width=20).place(x=10,y=50)
        self.userentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.userentered)
        self.userentry.place(x=160,y=50)
        Button(self.master,text="Search Details",command=self.searchnames,width=15).place(x=300,y=50)
```

```
db=sqlite3.connect('project races.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        u = self.userentered.get()
        sql = "SELECT Name from AthleteDetails where username = ?"
        cursor.execute(sql,(u,))
        name = cursor.fetchone()

        sql = "SELECT DOB from AthleteDetails where username = ?"
        cursor.execute(sql,(u,))
        dob = cursor.fetchone()

        sql = "SELECT Gender from AthleteDetails where username = ?"
        cursor.execute(sql,(u,))
        gender = cursor.fetchone()

        sql = "SELECT Email from AthleteDetails where username = ?"
        cursor.execute(sql,(u,))
        email = cursor.fetchone()

        sql = "SELECT Club from AthleteDetails where username = ?"
        cursor.execute(sql,(u,))
        club = cursor.fetchone()
```

```
Label(self.master,text="Full Name",width=20).place(x=10,y=70)
        self.nameentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=name,state=DISABLED)
        self.nameentry.place(x=150,y=70)

        Label(self.master,text="Date of Birth",width=20).place(x=10,y=90)
        self.dobentered = Entry(self.master,textvariable=dob,state=DISABLED)
        self.dobentered.place(x=150,y=90)

        Label(self.master,text="Gender",width=20).place(x=10,y=110)
        self.genderBox = Entry(self.master,textvariable=gender,state=DISABLED)
        self.genderBox.place(x=150,y=110)
    
        Label(self.master,text="Club",width=20).place(x=10,y=130)
        self.clubentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=club,state=DISABLED)
        self.clubentry.place(x=150,y=130)

        Label(self.master,text="Email",width=20).place(x=10,y=150)
        self.emailentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=email,state=DISABLED)
        self.emailentry.place(x=150,y=150)
        
        Label(self.master,text="Time prediction:",font=(14)).place(x=10,y=170)
        time = StringVar()
        self.timeentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=time)
        self.timeentry.place(x=150,y=170)
        Label(self.master,text="*To nearest minute",font=(12)).place(x=300,y=170)
```

[I want the entry boxes to be filled with the users data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA7vf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Change the state to normal, insert the data using the widget's `insert` method, then change it back to disabled.

```
self.nameentry.configure(state="normal")
self.nameentry.delete(0, "end")  # only necessary if it previously had a value
self.nameentry.insert(0,name)
self.nameentry.configure(state="disabled")
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `name`, `dob`, `gender`, `email` and `club` may be `None` (no record found in database) or a `tuple` (record found in database).  They are not instances of `StringVar()`, so using them as `textvariable` option of `Entry` widget will not update the widgets automatically.

Also you can use one SQL query to fetch all of them instead of five SQL queries, and then create those instances of `StringVar()` with the result of SQL query as below:

```py
db = sqlite3.connect('project races.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
u = self.userentered.get()
# use single SQL query to get all the information
sql = "SELECT Name, DOB, Gender, Email, Club FROM AthleteDetails WHERE username = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, (u,))
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result:
    # create required StringVar and set their values
    name = StringVar(value=result[0])
    dob = StringVar(value=result[1])
    gender = StringVar(value=result[2])
    email = StringVar(value=result[3])
    club = StringVar(value=result[4])

    # user details
    Label(self.master,text="Full Name",width=20).place(x=10,y=70)
    self.nameentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=name,state=DISABLED)
    self.nameentry.place(x=150,y=70)

    Label(self.master,text="Date of Birth",width=20).place(x=10,y=90)
    self.dobentered = Entry(self.master,textvariable=dob,state=DISABLED)
    self.dobentered.place(x=150,y=90)

    Label(self.master,text="Gender",width=20).place(x=10,y=110)
    self.genderBox = Entry(self.master,textvariable=gender,state=DISABLED)
    self.genderBox.place(x=150,y=110)

    Label(self.master,text="Club",width=20).place(x=10,y=130)
    self.clubentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=club,state=DISABLED)
    self.clubentry.place(x=150,y=130)

    Label(self.master,text="Email",width=20).place(x=10,y=150)
    self.emailentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=email,state=DISABLED)
    self.emailentry.place(x=150,y=150)

    Label(self.master,text="Time prediction:",font=(14)).place(x=10,y=170)
    time = StringVar()
    self.timeentry=Entry(self.master,textvariable=time)
    self.timeentry.place(x=150,y=170)
    Label(self.master,text="*To nearest minute",font=(12)).place(x=300,y=170)
```

Comment: works perfect that mate, cheers